# Condition inside a json array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, charts

I am using a library called `chartjs` to print the graphics on my screen. For that, I am passing an array of objects that should be displayed in this graph. The problem is that I just want that last object to appear if the `state` is equal to `'yes`'. If I remove this conditional, the code works perfectly. Any suggestions on how I could solve this problem?

```
[
       {
          data1: 'mydata01',
          data2: 'mydata02',
       },
       {
          data3: 'mydata03',
          data4: 'mydata04',
       },
    this.state.condition === 'yes' ? (
       {
          data3: 'mydata03',
          data4: 'mydata04',
       },
      ) : 'remove'
    ]
```

Comment: You can keep the `if` condition outside the array initialization logic?

Comment: Not ideal. But it could be an alternative.

Comment: JSON is a syntax for storing and exchanging data.it is text, written with JavaScript(JS) object notation. Basically used for exchange of Data & does not Take Conditional Statements. When exchanging data between a browser and a server, the data can only be text.
We can convert any JS object into JSON, and send JSON to the server & can also convert any JSON received from the server into JS objects. This way we can work with the data as JS objects, with no complicated parsing and translations. You may process the data using Various Condition Statements such as `if...Else`, `Case...EndCase`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the characteristics of the spread operator, you can do it like the code below. The spread operator adds nothing if the subsequent value is an empty array.

```js
var condition = 'yes';
var arr = [{
    data1: 'mydata01',
    data2: 'mydata02',
  },
  {
    data3: 'mydata03',
    data4: 'mydata04',
  },
  ...(condition === 'yes' ? (
    [{
      data3: 'mydata03',
      data4: 'mydata04',
    }]
  ) : [])
]

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using this array somewhere, (we'll call it `usage`), your best bet is to split it out:

```
usage = [
  {
     data1: 'mydata01',
     data2: 'mydata02',
  },
  {
    data3: 'mydata03',
    data4: 'mydata04',
  }
];

if (this.state.condition === 'yes') {
  usage = [
    ...usage, 
    {
      data3: 'mydata03',
      data4: 'mydata04',
    }
  ];
}
```

reasoning being, if you put your condition inside the array `[1, 2, (test ? 3 : null)]` you'll end up with `[1, 2, 3]` or `[1, 2, null]` and you likely want to avoid the second one as it could break the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice(startPosition, length)`

`const dataToShow = data.slice(0,  this.state.condition === 'yes' ? data.length : data.length - 1)`

Comment: Radical approach sir. We can recommend replacing the Condition Statement with some Specific and smaller value to be used for `slice`ing the data object, correct?